# Visual Studio Exporting GridView to Excel File, Not writing any data

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have added C# code behind my page to export GridView1 to an Excel file.  Issue is, it will create an Excel file, however, the only data is:  .textmode { }  shown in cell A1.  Gotta be something simple I am missing here...  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

```
protected void ExcelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();

    Response.Buffer = true;

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",

    "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");

    Response.Charset = "";

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

    GridView1.DataBind();

    //Change the Header Row back to white color

    GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");

    //Apply style to Individual Cells

    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "green");

    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "green");

    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "green");

    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "green");

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];

        //Change Color back to white

        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

        //Apply text style to each Row

        row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");

        //Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row

        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            row.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");

            row.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");

            row.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");

            row.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
        }
    }

    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

    //style to format numbers to string

    string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";

    Response.Write(style);

    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());

    Response.Flush();

    Response.End();

}
```

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML file with an .xls extension.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks.  I have never used that but completely willing to give it a try especially since it will be generating and actual Excel and not HTML file.  No pesky file format warning either.  I will give your link/documentation a try.  Thanks again.

Comment: My page does have two parameters (StartDate and EndDate) that will drive the results for the GridView.  Will I be able to create the spreadsheet of these dynamic results that will be in the current GridView using EPPlus?

Comment: Yes, you can fill the document with a DataTable: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/8223/filling-the-document-with-data/26422/fill-with-a-datatable#t=20170126074954756775

Comment: Thank you for that excellent Documentation.  So I see by your link you are creating the DataTable, then filling it with static data within your code.  So my question is, how do I create, or a least fill that DataTable with the content that currently resides in my GridView1.  Just a note, the GridView1 is populated via SqlDataSource1 along with the two parameters 'StartDate' and 'EndDate', then executed via a Button control.  That is where I am getting hung up.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It's the next example: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/8223/filling-the-document-with-data/26423/fill-with-a-datatable-from-an-sql-query-or-stored-procedure#t=20170126123324564655. There it shows you how to fill the DataTable also.

Comment: Thanks!  I have added my Select Statement as well as my ConnectionString info. When I click the button now, it appears to be running but I am not seeing any results.  Is there something else that needs to be done in order for it to create the file and prompt the user to Save As?